# vlookup doesn't work

Tags: excel, excel-2007

http://s3.amazonaws.com/alexa-static/top-1m.csv.zip

on that Alexa domain ranking spreadsheet (top 1 million domains in the world)

A column contains domain ranking, B column contains domain name (for those not familiar)

On a D column, I put
=VLOOKUP("dog",A1:B1000001,1,TRUE)

and it returns #N/A

How come Vlookup is not working ?

Using Excel 2007, Vista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052093351033.aspx) doctumentation

> The V in VLOOKUP stands for vertical.
>   Use VLOOKUP instead of HLOOKUP when
>   your comparison values are located in
>   a column to the left of the data that
>   you want to find.
>
> Table_array  Two or more columns of
>   data. Use a reference to a range or a
>   range name. **The values in the first
>   column of table_array are the values
>   searched by lookup_value.** These values
>   can be text, numbers, or logical
>   values. Uppercase and lowercase text
>   are equivalent.

From your formula, and the fact the the data in the sheet is ID, Value, this will try to match *dog* to an *ID ( integer )* value, which **should return no results**.

Also, the sort order of the lookup values are important

> The values in the first column of
>   table_array must be placed in
>   ascending sort order; otherwise,
>   VLOOKUP may not give the correct
>   value.

If RangeLookUp is set to FALSE

> If FALSE, VLOOKUP will only find an
>   exact match. In this case, the values
>   in the first column of table_array do
>   not need to be sorted.